# Arrow function as a parameter type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Can you please what is going on in this code
"block" parameter is taking type of arrow function which returns the promise with generic

```
  async sync<T>(block: (renderer: RendererExplorer) => Promise<T>) {
    return await block(this[rendererExplorerSymbol]);
  }
```

Comment: Are you just looking for [documentation on *function type expressions*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions)?  Or do you need something else?

Answer (score 0):

The function `sync` is generic, meaning that you will have to provide the type yourself when calling it, which should match the response of the function that you are passing as parameter.

Here is an example:

If you have a async render function that returns something, for example:

```
const myRender = async () => {
   await doingWork();
   return {status: true}
}
```

You render function is returning `Promise<{status: boolean}>`

Then if you want to call the `sync` function you will need to provide the type: `{status: boolean}` for example:

```
const result = await sync<{status: boolean}>(myRender);
```

As you can see the generic `T` that you provided (`{status: boolean}`) when calling the function should match the response of the async function which you supplied as parameter.

If they don't match you will get an TS error.

Hope this makes things more clear!

Comment: There is nothing forcing the user to supply `T` and one can make a case that they shouldn't, because a narrower type could be inferred and because at some point the value will have to be used and type checked anyway. This is not specific to generics: you could just as well write `const result: { status: boolean } = await sync(myRender)`. The best option being probably `const result = await sync(myRender) satisfies { status: boolean };` if you really really want to annotate every single thing you type in TS.

Comment: I 100% agree, you should not supply generic types if they can be inferred by TS. I did that explicitly for the example to become obvious what `T` refers to. You can certainly call `await sync(myRender)` and the type will be infered from `myRender`. But on the flip side there are cases where you do want to be explicit. For example Instantiation Expressions: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7-beta/#instantiation-expressions where you can define different `sync` methods from one generic one, etc.